# SAPUI5 creat a model return a warning

Tags: model, sapui5

I am trying to write my own util class and create a model, but I am getting a warning, I do not understand:

Warning Message:

```
EventProvider sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel path /$metadata should be absolute if no Context is set -
```

This is my code:

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {

    var Test = function () {};
    Test.prototype.PATH__TO_ROOT = "https://xxx/root";
    Test.prototype.configModel = function () {
        var configModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(this.PATH__TO_ROOT + "/someDetails.odata", true);
    };

    return new Test();
});
```

If I use a global variable it works without the warning, but then the WEB IDE does not autocompletes "Test".

Why do I get the warning and how can I fix this?

Best Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are using the depracated sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel. Instead, you should use either the V2 or V4 ODataModel (while the V4 might not have all features yet...). For details see here: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/

Like already mentioned in the other answer, you could also think about using the manifest.json to let UI5 instantiate the v2.ODataModel for you automatically. However, this is not a must - but it's kind of a best practice!

Instantiating the v2.ODataModel manually works just fine, too. However, the answer above claims that in your code you will get something like *https://somaddress.com//https://xxx/root/someDetails.odata* in the end, which is **absolutely wrong**. Have a look at my example [here](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/sapui5-single-file-template-using-xmlviews-controllers-fragments-and-custom-controls-for-bug-illustrations-support-requests-or-demos), so something like this would work just fine:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://www.myserver.copm/path/to/my/odata/service.svc/", {
    json : true,
    useBatch : false
});
//...
```

Of course, in the snippet above you might have to consider the same origin policy of your browser... In case you want to access an OData service on the same server you could use relative URLs:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/path/to/my/odata/service.svc/", {
    json : true,
    useBatch : false
});
//...
```

Comment: if I add the uri to the manifest.dataSources. How can I grab the model from there?

Comment: Under sap.ui.models in the manifest you can reference the dataSource. It depends if you have a "default" model (empty string) or a named model like at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html After which you can use it in the whole component just as usual, i.e. either in a controller with this.getModel("modelName") or in the XMLViews. Did you read the walkthrough tutorial? If not have a look at it, it should help you...

Comment: thanks, but I am not inside a Controller, but inside a util class. So far it seems to be working, but the following worked prior and is no working with v2. 

    var url = "/FieldsConfig?$filter=FIELD_ID eq '" + fieldId + "'";
 oModel.read( url, {...

It cuts the url at the questionmark.

Comment: Please open a new question for that as it gets a little off topic. Anyway, I believe you should have a look at the tutorials because this is in there...

Comment: found it. Had to go into serviceUrlParams

Answer (score 1):

SAPUI5 treats all strings that begins from `/` as an absolute path. In your example PATH__TO_ROOT not starts from the `/`, so it is thinking that you declaring relative path.

Actually it is not the way like oData usually get service url. ODataModel will take a host name of you currently launched application and will concat service url to that. In your case it will lead to something close like this string.

`https://somaddress.com//https://xxx/root/someDetails.odata`

That is wrong.
And the second thing,consider use of metadata.json or metadata part (depends from your SAPUI5 version), in order to make SAPUI5 do the work for you and create appropriate path ODataModel.

**part of manifest.json example**

```
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "appid",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "dataSources": {
            "mainService": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/exampleapp/someodata",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0",
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You don't need to create ODataModel manually.